# React native + SSL socket: Error: xhr poll error

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, react-native

I'm using `socket.io-client` to connect socket from react native app with ssl socket server and get an error at `connect-error` event - `[Error: xhr poll error]`.

Here is my code from react native (client side):

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import Config from '../../config';

var socketConfig = {
    secure: true
}

function connect() {
    this.socket = io(Config.notificationUrl, socketConfig);
    // this.socket.connect();

    this.socket.on('connect', () => console.log("Socket connected", self.socket.id));
    this.socket.on('connect_error', (err) => console.log("connect_error", err));
    this.socket.on('error', (err) => console.log("error", err));
}
```

I have tried to add transports: ['websocket', 'polling'] to socketConfig, but I also got other error `[Error: websocket error]`. Also tried to use `import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'`, but not different.

**Note: I connect successful to socket server which use http protocol.**

I'm using react native 0.40.0 and socket.io-client 1.7.3.

Comment: Same. Any update on this?

Comment: I resolved this issue by change the server's configuration - add rejectUnauthorized = false to socket's config.

Answer (score 0):

if you set 'rejectUnauthorized = false', it's unsafe.

> https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-a-self-signed-certificate
>
> ```js
> // option 2. WARNING: it leaves you vulnerable to MITM attacks!
>   rejectUnauthorized: false
> ```

Answer (score 0):

install `2.4.0 socket.io client`.

this version has `engine.io 3.5.0`

It's resolve my issue.